# Cpagination and search issue in yii

Tags: php, search, yii, pagination

This is Cpagination action, when I do a search that have 3 results for example it gives me 3 pages, each page have the same 3 three results, so what is the wrong here:

```
 $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
            $models = Files::model();
            if (isset($_GET['file'])) {
                $q = $_GET['file'];
                $criteria->compare('fileName', $q, true, 'OR');
                $criteria->compare('tags', $q, true, 'OR');
                $count=Files::model()->count($criteria);
                $pages=new CPagination($count);

                // results per page
                $pages->pageSize=1;
               // $pages->applyLimit($criteria);

            }

            $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider("Files", array('criteria' => $criteria));
            $this->render('result', array(
                'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
                'pages'=>$pages,
                    ));
```

this is the view:

```
<?php


$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'itemView' => '_view',
));
$this->widget('CLinkPager', array(
    'pages' => $pages,
)) ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using meshed things inside your code. Also, your `$pages->pageSize` will runs only when `isset($_GET['file'])`. `if` statement must be used only for adding criteria parameters.

You must decide will you use only either `Files::model()` or `CActiveDataProvider("Files")`. If you will use `CActiveDataProvider`:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();

if ( isset($_GET['file']) ) {
    $criteria->compare('fileName', $_GET['file'], true, 'OR');
    $criteria->compare('tags', $_GET['file'], true, 'OR');
}

$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider("Files", array(
    'criteria' => $criteria,
    'countCriteria' => $criteria,
    'pagination'=>array(
        // results per page
        'pageSize'=>1,
    ),
));

$this->render('result', array(
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'pages' => $dataProvider->pagination,
));
```

Also, I can't see your `view`. Maybe you have some wrong pagination code there too.

Comment: countCriteria is not defined, i want to use Files::model(), and i'll edit the question and show u the view

Comment: Oops. `countCriteria` for `CActiveDataProvider` was introduced in Yii 1.1.14. What the version you're using? Try to remove `'countCriteria' => $criteria,` at all.

Comment: ya i removed it and removed the pagination widget from the view, now it's work fine, thank you :)